# Visiting all locations in a multidimensional array directly adjacent to some location?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm doing my first algorithm (A* Pathfinding) and part of it involves checking all nodes adjacent to a different node. Is there a quick and easy way to do this or must it be done manually for each node?

**Edit:**

By adjacent I mean this:

Each X is adjacent to the parent node, O

```
XXX  
XOX  
XXX
```

Comment: depends on your datastructure... :)

Comment: Can you describe what exactly you mean by adjacent node?  Do you mean neighbouring entries in the array?

Comment: Post your code. It's hard to know what you're talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a nice double-for-loop you can use:

```
for (int i = x - 1; i <= x + 1; i++) {
    for (int j = y - 1; j <= y + 1; j++) {
        /* Skip the point itself! */
        if (i == x && j == y) continue;

        /* Process the location here */
    }
}
```

This can also be generalized to only consider points adjacent by cardinal directions (i.e. directly up/down/left/right).  To do that, you use a modification of the above for loop where you visit all eight neighbors, but then skip points that either

- Are identically where you are (both `i == x` and `j == y`), or
- Have neither x nor y in common with the start point (both `i != x` and `j != y`)

Interestingly, the above two tests can be rolled into one line: `((i == x) == (j == y))`.  This tests whether both values are the same (you're at the same place you started) or both values are different (you're on a diagonal):

```
for (int i = x - 1; i <= x + 1; i++) {
    for (int j = y - 1; j <= y + 1; j++) {
        if ((i == x) == (j == y)) continue;

        /* Process the location here */
    }
}
```

Of course, in both cases you should ensure that you're within the bounds of the world, but since I don't know how those are specified I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader. :-)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The adjacent entries in a 2D array are pretty easy to find.  The adjacent entries to `array[i][j]` are:

```
array[i-1][j-1];
array[i-1][j];
array[i-1][j+1];
array[i][j-1];
array[i][j+1];
array[i+1][j-1];
array[i+1][j];
array[i+1][j+1];
```

You can generalize to higher-dimensioned arrays pretty easily. Watch out that you don't go past the bounds of your array!

Comment: Hardcoding these locations is error-prone, hard-to-read, and not easily generalizable to higher dimensions.

Comment: It's also pretty convenient to package the offsets inside an array and just iterate over that, saves the hassle with double loops.